# JDBC getConnection is not working on Tomcat server. But it is running as a Java Application

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have the code as below, which worked perfectly fine when I ran it as a Java Application:

```
package com.LearnersLingoo.WebContent;
```

// Consider all the necessary imports are taken care

```
public class VerifyUser {

    public VerifyUser(){

    }
    boolean userExist(String userName, String userPassword){
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRes = null;

        try{
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "student", null);
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate("insert into learners" + 
                                        "(ID, userName, FirstName, LastName, Password)" +
                                        "values" + 
                                        "(11001, 'Test', 'testUser', 'UserLastN', 'password')");

            System.out.println("Rows inserted: " + rowsAffected);
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

The console message is as below:

```
Connection Successful
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '11001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here anyway the user is already present, so atleast the connection is successful.

When I have the similar code run as a Servlet I am getting

```
Connnnection not successfuljava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

I have gone through other similar questions on this topic which suggested me to add class.forname( com.mysql.jdbc.driver ) But it did not help

```
@WebServlet
public class HomePage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection connection;   
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HomePage() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void init(){
        try {
            // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "student", null);
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");

        } catch (SQLException  e) {
            System.out.println("Connnnection not successful");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Kindly help me on how to add the JDBC jar on Tomcat server. I am running Tomcat server for my web application in Eclipse installed on Mac.

Updated full stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.LearnersLingoo.WebContent.HomePage.init(HomePage.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
Connnnection not successful
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You need to add the JDBC JAR file to your WAR file.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by doing this: I added the mySQL JDBC jar file to Tomcat Server  using Tomcat Server  "Open Launch Configuration" --> ClassPath. This resolved the issue. Could you please tell me if this is correct way to resolve the issue? So in total I added the JDBC driver at two places. 1) To the web application classpath and 2) to the Tomcat server classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am able to resolve this issue by doing this: 
I added the MySQL JDBC jar file to Tomcat Server using Tomcat Server "Open Launch Configuration" --> ClassPath. This resolved the issue. 
Could you please tell me if this is the correct way to resolve the issue ? 
So in total, I added the JDBC driver at two places.
1) To the web application classpath
2) to the Tomcat server classpath**

You don't need to add the `JAR` in both the places, the best practice is to make  it available to the respective web application's classpath (i.e., `WEB-INF/lib`).

Also, rather than adding it manually, ensure that your build tool (Maven, Gradle, etc) packages all required dependencies for you to the project's `lib` folder. So, when you deploy the project into the server, the JAR will be available in the respective `lib` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going through adding dependencies manually and your answer explained me about the use of build tools. I will try to do this using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to with the  ($CATALINA_HOME/lib)
As I have not configured the environment variable $CATALINA_HOME. I have to add the jdbc driver to the server classpath that I am running my local code which is the Tomcat web container.

So adding the mySQL JDBC jar file to Tomcat Server using Tomcat Server "Open Launch Configuration" --> ClassPath. This resolved the issue.

So in total I added the JDBC driver at two places. 1) To the web application classpath and 2) to the Tomcat server classpath

Actually adding the driver to the web application class path is not required. As this is already taken from the server classpath first.